# How to include category url keys in product URLs

Tags: magento2, category, url, certification, associatedevelopercertification

I am preparing to get Magento certified, doing some test questions I have found this:

> A client has asked you to include category url keys in product URLs.
> How is this done?
>
> ```
> A. Create an observer for controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_view
> B. This is not possible because products can belong to multiple categories
> C. Set the configuration value of catalog/seo/product_use_categories to Yes
> D. Create an after plugin on \Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router::generateRewrite
> ```

The answer marked as correct is D but I think the correct answer is C.

Can someone give me their opinion on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is the correct answer, sometimes you can see an incorrect answer when taking the Online sample test.

Comment: I thought so but wanted to make sure. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Cheers!